# Unexpected lines on matplotlib subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to make subplots for each column of a dataframe (copied below), where each subplot has five lines: one for each set of indices (the index of the df is 0:100 repeating 5 times).

This code is running fine, but each subplot unexpectedly has several extra lines. Does anyone know why this is and how they can be removed?

```
df.plot(subplots=True)
plt.show()
```

**code output:**
[image: code output]

**df**

```
     fallowDeer  longhornCattle  arableGrass      woodland
1      0.007450        0.346674     1.790945  6.735817e+00
2      0.007652        0.359393     1.787792  6.762532e+00
3      0.007855        0.372231     1.784598  6.789168e+00
4      0.008064        0.385602     1.781230  6.815451e+00
5      0.008279        0.399516     1.777682  6.841365e+00
6      0.008499        0.413975     1.773955  6.866912e+00
7      0.008725        0.428977     1.770050  6.892092e+00
8      0.008957        0.444574     1.765953  6.916852e+00
9      0.009195        0.460814     1.761649  6.941138e+00
10     0.009439        0.477699     1.757140  6.964952e+00
11     0.009690        0.495227     1.752424  6.988293e+00
12     0.009946        0.513229     1.747547  7.011344e+00
13     0.010210        0.532317     1.742348  7.033449e+00
14     0.010481        0.552096     1.736931  7.055032e+00
15     0.010759        0.572595     1.731288  7.076061e+00
16     0.011043        0.593844     1.725412  7.096504e+00
17     0.011335        0.615910     1.719286  7.116288e+00
18     0.011633        0.638837     1.712900  7.135367e+00
19     0.011939        0.662664     1.706244  7.153697e+00
20     0.012253        0.687430     1.699309  7.171237e+00
21     0.012574        0.713173     1.692085  7.187946e+00
22     0.012903        0.739933     1.684561  7.203782e+00
23     0.013241        0.767748     1.676730  7.218703e+00
24     0.013586        0.796658     1.668581  7.232665e+00
25     0.013939        0.826705     1.660110  7.245619e+00
26     0.014301        0.857927     1.651307  7.257523e+00
27     0.014671        0.890366     1.642164  7.268332e+00
28     0.015050        0.924059     1.632672  7.278003e+00
29     0.015437        0.959047     1.622822  7.286493e+00
30     0.015833        0.995370     1.612607  7.293757e+00
31     0.016237        1.033067     1.602017  7.299752e+00
32     0.016651        1.072196     1.591045  7.304410e+00
33     0.017073        1.112807     1.579685  7.307672e+00
34     0.017503        1.154947     1.567927  7.309485e+00
35     0.017943        1.198662     1.555765  7.309798e+00
36     0.018391        1.243996     1.543190  7.308558e+00
37     0.018849        1.290996     1.530194  7.305715e+00
38     0.019315        1.339707     1.516769  7.301217e+00
39     0.019791        1.390176     1.502909  7.295008e+00
40     0.020275        1.442454     1.488616  7.287020e+00
41     0.020767        1.496589     1.473883  7.277197e+00
42     0.021268        1.552630     1.458707  7.265480e+00
43     0.021778        1.610622     1.443082  7.251815e+00
44     0.022296        1.670613     1.427002  7.236144e+00
45     0.022823        1.732651     1.410463  7.218410e+00
46     0.023357        1.796783     1.393458  7.198558e+00
47     0.023900        1.863027     1.376001  7.176551e+00
48     0.024450        1.931390     1.358112  7.152358e+00
49     0.025007        2.001907     1.339790  7.125931e+00
50     0.025571        2.074616     1.321038  7.097220e+00
51     0.026141        2.149555     1.301857  7.066176e+00
52     0.026718        2.226759     1.282247  7.032748e+00
53     0.027302        2.306266     1.262210  6.996888e+00
54     0.027891        2.388112     1.241746  6.958545e+00
55     0.028486        2.472335     1.220858  6.917671e+00
56     0.029087        2.558972     1.199544  6.874215e+00
57     0.029693        2.648058     1.177808  6.828129e+00
58     0.030305        2.739614     1.155656  6.779378e+00
59     0.030920        2.833502     1.133154  6.728063e+00
60     0.031539        2.929679     1.110331  6.674205e+00
61     0.032160        3.028138     1.087205  6.617792e+00
62     0.032784        3.128872     1.063793  6.558813e+00
63     0.033409        3.231873     1.040113  6.497257e+00
64     0.034036        3.337134     1.016181  6.433113e+00
65     0.034663        3.444649     0.992014  6.366368e+00
66     0.035291        3.554410     0.967631  6.297013e+00
67     0.035919        3.666409     0.943048  6.225035e+00
68     0.036546        3.780516     0.918308  6.150545e+00
69     0.037172        3.896503     0.893473  6.073748e+00
70     0.037795        4.014299     0.868574  5.994693e+00
71     0.038415        4.133837     0.843641  5.913429e+00
72     0.039032        4.255048     0.818703  5.830004e+00
73     0.039645        4.377864     0.793790  5.744469e+00
74     0.040253        4.502215     0.768932  5.656870e+00
75     0.040856        4.628034     0.744160  5.567258e+00
76     0.041453        4.755253     0.719502  5.475680e+00
77     0.042044        4.883781     0.694989  5.382208e+00
78     0.042628        5.013319     0.670666  5.287137e+00
79     0.043205        5.143688     0.646568  5.190635e+00
80     0.043774        5.274761     0.622728  5.092813e+00
81     0.044335        5.406410     0.599180  4.993782e+00
82     0.044887        5.538509     0.575956  4.893656e+00
83     0.045430        5.670929     0.553091  4.792544e+00
84     0.045963        5.803542     0.530617  4.690560e+00
85     0.046486        5.936223     0.508567  4.587815e+00
86     0.046998        6.068842     0.486975  4.484421e+00
87     0.047499        6.201237     0.465852  4.380545e+00
88     0.047989        6.333211     0.445191  4.276401e+00
89     0.048469        6.464619     0.425012  4.172133e+00
90     0.048937        6.595313     0.405337  4.067880e+00
91     0.049394        6.725149     0.386189  3.963782e+00
92     0.049839        6.853978     0.367590  3.859980e+00
93     0.050272        6.981656     0.349561  3.756615e+00
94     0.050693        7.108037     0.332124  3.653825e+00
95     0.051102        7.232974     0.315302  3.551752e+00
96     0.051498        7.356327     0.299111  3.450532e+00
97     0.051881        7.478031     0.283512  3.350258e+00
98     0.052253        7.597997     0.268485  3.251037e+00
99     0.052613        7.716121     0.254019  3.152984e+00
100    0.052961        7.832296     0.240106  3.056217e+00
1      0.006563        0.291718    32.789075  1.333297e+01
2      0.009306        0.319637    32.734934  1.340290e+01
3      0.013171        0.350146    32.673403  1.346950e+01
4      0.018631        0.383501    32.603701  1.353229e+01
5      0.026355        0.419958    32.525022  1.359068e+01
6      0.037262        0.459785    32.436500  1.364405e+01
7      0.052644        0.503266    32.337159  1.369165e+01
8      0.074326        0.550710    32.225898  1.373256e+01
9      0.104867        0.602441    32.101466  1.376569e+01
10     0.147815        0.658804    31.962428  1.378969e+01
11     0.208110        0.720158    31.807114  1.380288e+01
12     0.292610        0.786880    31.633559  1.380311e+01
13     0.410798        0.859358    31.439408  1.378768e+01
14     0.575632        0.937987    31.221823  1.375309e+01
15     0.804784        1.023164    30.977330  1.369484e+01
16     1.122258        1.115278    30.701625  1.360710e+01
17     1.560257        1.214695    30.389358  1.348241e+01
18     2.161433        1.321742    30.033861  1.331126e+01
19     2.981374        1.436683    29.626857  1.308180e+01
20     4.091413        1.559686    29.158125  1.277955e+01
21     5.580628        1.690783    28.615251  1.238766e+01
22     7.556279        1.829815    27.983564  1.188768e+01
23    10.142112        1.976379    27.246316  1.126121e+01
24    13.471800        2.129759    26.385436  1.049319e+01
25    17.675018        2.288828    25.383197  9.577591e+00
26    22.851891        2.452014    24.225502  8.524131e+00
27    29.070012        2.617409    22.902461  7.355920e+00
28    36.306696        2.782595    21.416281  6.123656e+00
29    44.460749        2.944967    19.780943  4.890227e+00
30    53.341140        3.101736    18.024156  3.730597e+00
31    62.665838        3.250283    16.190350  2.709652e+00
32    72.135122        3.388231    14.329141  1.875659e+00
33    81.431174        3.513897    12.498429  1.235189e+00
34    90.283522        3.626215    10.749649  7.755081e-01
35    98.482725        3.724818     9.124936  4.659983e-01
36   105.891384        3.809961     7.653623  2.688322e-01
37   112.440348        3.882392     6.351458  1.493003e-01
38   118.117413        3.943199     5.222205  8.019041e-02
39   122.958408        3.993674     4.259510  4.197606e-02
40   127.027573        4.035164     3.450909  2.144544e-02
41   130.406720        4.068989     2.780080  1.075486e-02
42   133.184325        4.096376     2.229253  5.294279e-03
43   135.448207        4.118426     1.780761  2.579653e-03
44   137.280540        4.136097     1.418105  1.242850e-03
45   138.755154        4.150205     1.126490  5.934029e-04
46   139.936420        4.161434     0.893051  2.819022e-04
47   140.879184        4.170351     0.706854  1.330716e-04
48   141.629361        4.177418     0.558765  6.264137e-05
49   142.224875        4.183010     0.441253  2.933984e-05
50   142.696670        4.187428     0.348184  1.378083e-05
51   143.069904        4.190917     0.274577  6.401766e-06
52   143.364858        4.193670     0.216419  2.921174e-06
53   143.597716        4.195840     0.170513  1.345607e-06
54   143.781413        4.197551     0.134303  6.126557e-07
55   143.926313        4.198899     0.105743  2.543404e-07
56   144.040559        4.199961     0.083227  9.595042e-08
57   144.130610        4.200798     0.065481  1.332503e-07
58   144.201315        4.201455     0.051547  4.231664e-07
59   144.256974        4.201972     0.040580  6.358084e-07
60   144.300837        4.202379     0.031937  5.250733e-07
61   144.335385        4.202700     0.025129  6.508542e-09
62   144.362584        4.202953     0.019770 -4.208388e-07
63   144.383970        4.203151     0.015556 -3.225375e-07
64   144.400789        4.203307     0.012242  4.201597e-07
65   144.414032        4.203430     0.009633  1.169475e-06
66   144.424453        4.203527     0.007579  1.024171e-06
67   144.432658        4.203603     0.005963 -1.395606e-07
68   144.439112        4.203663     0.004692 -1.635783e-06
69   144.444187        4.203710     0.003692 -1.572348e-06
70   144.448183        4.203747     0.002904 -7.156491e-07
71   144.451327        4.203776     0.002285 -3.133699e-07
72   144.453800        4.203799     0.001798 -1.801740e-07
73   144.455747        4.203817     0.001414 -8.406506e-08
74   144.457279        4.203831     0.001112 -3.503717e-08
75   144.458482        4.203843     0.000875 -1.859228e-08
76   144.459432        4.203851     0.000688 -8.927865e-09
77   144.460172        4.203858     0.000542 -3.989782e-09
78   144.460758        4.203864     0.000427 -1.203336e-09
79   144.461221        4.203868     0.000335  4.085075e-10
80   144.461584        4.203871     0.000264  9.615269e-10
81   144.461869        4.203874     0.000208  7.148805e-10
82   144.462094        4.203876     0.000163  1.032411e-10
83   144.462270        4.203878     0.000129 -3.866422e-10
84   144.462410        4.203879     0.000101 -3.884383e-10
85   144.462520        4.203880     0.000079  1.702438e-10
86   144.462607        4.203881     0.000062  1.313226e-09
87   144.462675        4.203881     0.000049  2.477659e-09
88   144.462728        4.203882     0.000038  3.247596e-09
89   144.462770        4.203882     0.000030  3.123338e-09
90   144.462803        4.203883     0.000024  1.727332e-09
91   144.462829        4.203883     0.000019 -6.657306e-10
92   144.462849        4.203883     0.000015 -3.897599e-09
93   144.462865        4.203883     0.000011 -7.076999e-09
94   144.462878        4.203883     0.000009 -9.169994e-09
95   144.462888        4.203883     0.000007 -9.397577e-09
96   144.462895        4.203883     0.000005 -7.048286e-09
97   144.462902        4.203884     0.000004 -2.284339e-09
98   144.462906        4.203884     0.000003  5.076956e-09
99   144.462910        4.203884     0.000003  1.229899e-08
100  144.462913        4.203884     0.000002  1.305200e-08
1      0.006330        0.309322    26.442387  2.224354e-01
2      0.007378        0.352436    26.565959  2.236923e-01
...
99     3.637201       69.910416     0.002712  5.950206e-09
100    3.637252       69.911266     0.002319  5.023733e-09
1      0.006381        0.337560    14.216094  8.925055e+00
2      0.006994        0.369206    14.262931  8.969356e+00
...
99     0.478647       22.448542     0.045725  2.797452e-02
100    0.478778       22.454571     0.041094  2.509687e-02
1      0.006489        0.277453    29.890613  8.099429e+00
2      0.008367        0.316823    30.022854  8.104243e+00
....
99    19.569625       17.644414     0.000485  2.045739e-06
100   19.569682       17.644438     0.000412  1.634573e-06
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Cause of the problem

This is happening because the matplotlib backend is drawing one line that goes through all of your points, instead of one line for each group of indices.

### Example

```py
indices = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
y_values = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
plt.plot(indices, y_values)
plt.show()
```

[image: problem example]

## Solution

Add a grouping variable and plot with seaborn.

```py
grouping_variable = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
example_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'y_values': y_values, 'group': grouping_variable}, index=indices
)
sns.lineplot(x=example_df.index, y=example_df['y_values'], hue=example_df['group'])
```

[image: solution]